# Show only a part of a list - Button to Switch View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing with a problem.
As you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cwv1sbm/3/
I have a list with 16 elements, where I've hided the seconds 8 with css, using :

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1n+9) {
 display: none;
}
```

I want to create a button that on-click shows the next 8 elements of the list and if it is clicked again comes back to the first 8 view...

My purpose is to see only 8 elements at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo**

Used to **[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.button').on('click', function(){

  $('ul li').toggle();
  });


});
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(1n+9) {display: none;}

.button {
  background-color: #ed241a;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="carter" class="products">
  <li>1<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">16</li>
</ul>
<br>
 <a href="#" class="button">Switch View</a>
```

Comment: Hi, i wanted to see only 8 element at the time

Comment: @APPRAILY I have updatd to my answer accroding to your requirement please chekc it

Comment: Seems to work, but it loose css formattation....!! Thanks mate, i'll try to put it on line

Comment: I've tried your solution, but i forgot to write that in the site i have to implement the code, the css is : ul#carter li:nth-of-type(n+9) {display: none!important}...I have to add _!important_ so the script doesn't works... Any suggestion  @Rohit Azad,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(".button").click(function() {

  if ($("li").not(":visible").length > 0) {
    $("li:visible").toggle("slow");
    $("li").not(":visible").toggle("slow").addClass("shown");

  } else {
    $("li").not(".shown").toggle("slow");
    $(".shown").toggle("slow").removeClass("shown");
  }

});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5cLvq6bm/)

Comment: Hey, your method work with all list, fact in the one i have to implement it the css is : ul#carter li:nth-of-type(n+9) {display: none!important}...I have to add !important, so the script doesn't works... Any suggestion ?

Comment: then you will have to use the `.attr('style')` to manipulate the classes instead of `toggle` and/or `addClass`/`removeClass`

Comment: I've tried few times, but when i add display:none as .attr('style'), my list is not visible anymore so - if ($("li").not(":visible").length > 0) - doesn't works...it's struggling...